# Вопрос о задаче - подскажите пожалуйста, по какому принципу Петя заполнял матрицы? приведенный в примере алгоритм я не могу понять

Tags: java, алгоритм, матрицы

Петя решил сделать программный фон для своего мобильного приложения.
Петя определился, что фон будет зависеть от разрешения экрана. Поэтому мы будем считать, что экран имеет разрешение
W
×
H
, т.е.
H
строк пикселей по
W
в каждой строке.

Для определения интенсивности пикселей (некоторое целое число) Петя использует следующий алгоритм:

```
for row_min from 0 to H - 1  
  for row_max from row_min to H - 1  
    for col_min from 0 to W - 1  
      for col_max from col_min to W - 1  
        * for each pixel in this rectangle increase  
        * value by one
```

Например, если

W=4 и H=3
, то матрица интенсивности у Пети будет такая:

```
12 18 18 12  
16 24 24 16  
12 18 18 12
```

Если W=10 и H=10,
то матрица интенсивности у Пети будет такая:

```
100 180 240 280 300 300 280 240 180 100  
180 324 432 504 540 540 504 432 324 180  
240 432 576 672 720 720 672 576 432 240  
280 504 672 784 840 840 784 672 504 280  
300 540 720 840 900 900 840 720 540 300  
300 540 720 840 900 900 840 720 540 300  
280 504 672 784 840 840 784 672 504 280  
240 432 576 672 720 720 672 576 432 240  
180 324 432 504 540 540 504 432 324 180  
100 180 240 280 300 300 280 240 180 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При 3 строках и 4 столбцах

```
var rows = 3;
var cols = 4;

var map = new int[rows, cols];

for (int row_min = 0; row_min < rows; row_min++)
    for (int row_max = row_min; row_max < rows; row_max++)
        for (int col_min = 0; col_min < cols; col_min++)
            for (int col_max = col_min; col_max < cols; col_max++)
            {
                for (int i = row_min; i <= row_max; i++)
                    for (int j = col_min; j <= col_max; j++)
                        map[i, j]++;
            }
```

Вывод

[image: ...]

При 10х10

[image: ...]

По сути, формула считает для каждой клетки, сколько возможных прямоугольников содержат клетку. Формула делает это перебором, но можно сильно ускорить заполнение матрицы вот так

```
var map2 = new int[rows, cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        int x1 = i + 1;
        int y1 = j + 1;

        int x2 = rows - i;
        int y2 = cols - j;

        map2[i, j] = x1 * y1 * x2 * y2;
    }
```

Результат будет идентичный.